# Python initialization segfault

Tags: c++, python, boost, initialization, segmentation-fault

I'm building app with boost.python. I have some singleton class named `ScriptsManager`, it has function `initPython` which does:

```
mMainModule = bp::import("__main__");
mMainNamespace = bp::import("__dict__");

bp::object ignored = bp::exec("hello = file('hello.txt', 'w')\n"
                  "hello.write('Hello world!')\n"
                  "hello.close()", mMainNamespace);
```

both `mMainModule, mMainNamespace` are `boost::python::object`.

So, when I start application, I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff5d5efd9 in PyEval_GetGlobals () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#2  0x00007ffff5d79113 in PyImport_Import () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#3  0x00007ffff5d7935c in PyImport_ImportModule () from /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#4  0x00007ffff5a6d8bd in boost::python::import(boost::python::str) () from /usr/lib/libboost_python.so.1.46.0
#5  0x0000000000510b1b in ScriptsManager::initPython (this=0x7b6850) at /home/ockonal/Workspace/Themisto/src/Core/ScriptsManager.cpp:24
#6  0x0000000000547650 in Application::main (args=...) at /home/ockonal/Workspace/Themisto/src/main.cpp:60
#7  0x00007ffff4ebbf86 in main () from /usr/lib/libclan22App-2.2.so.1
#8  0x00007ffff24c4dcd in __libc_start_main () from /lib/libc.so.6
#9  0x00000000004c9769 in _start ()
```

What could be wrong here?

---

**UPD1**

When I call `Py_Initialize()` before `bp::import` I get:

> terminate called after throwing an
>   instance of
>   'boost::python::error_already_set'

---

**UPD2**

Seems that problem was in code:

```
mMainNamespace = bp::import("__dict__");
```

The result code is:

```
Py_Initialize();
mMainModule = bp::import("__main__");
mMainNamespace = mMainModule.attr("__dict__");
```

I'm not sure it's right.

---

**UPD3**

Yep, **2**-nd update works. So strange, `mMainNamespace = bp::import("__dict__")` is written in official boost docs.

Comment: Can you clarify: are you embedding boost python, or loading a module from python written in c++? Or, some combination of both....

Comment: I need both. The first is to init python using boost.python lib from c++ and after that do everything I want (running my own modules too).

Comment: So this segfault is happening to a c++ host process that's embedding python which then loads the (same or different?) code as a module?

Comment: @autopulated Now my c++ ap does only that code I noticed in this post. Forget about own modules. I can't run python code from c++.

Comment: Okay, so it's just plain embedding. I don't know what the problem is, but your code doesn't seem to relate to the examples on embedding boost python: (eg http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/EmbeddingPython or http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/EmbeddingPythonPart1.html)

Comment: @autopulated Okay, let's think the second link is helpful. Can you post an answer for my question to make me available mark it as right result.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question, or, see filmor's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is the following:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        // If you're going to use threads: PyEval_InitThreads();
        Py_Initialize();
        PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);

        bp::object mMainModule = bp::import('__main__');
        bp::object mMainNamespace = mMainModule.attr('__dict__');

        bp::object ignored = bp::exec("hello = file('hello.txt', 'w')\n"
              "hello.write('Hello world!')\n"
              "hello.close()", mMainNamespace);
   }
   catch (bp::error_already_set const&)
   {
        PyErr_Print();
   }
}
```

`Py_Initialize()` is necessary, the `try { ... } catch () { ... }`-block produces a Python error message like the one you would get from the interpreter and `bp::import` only works for modules, not for attributes of imported modules :-)

Comment: Thanks, I've already catched that. So strange that line is in official boost docs.